# Azure AD Enterprise application not showing 'automatic' provisioning mode

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I created a new Azure Active Directory (Azure Premium) with Bizpark subscription. I "Activated" 30 days free trial for Azure AD Premium.
Then I added an Enterprise application with "Non-gallery application" type.
But when I click on "Provisioning" I only see the manual option, where I am expecting the "automatic" to configure SCIM API integration

[image]

Then I followed steps in [Managing user account provisioning for enterprise apps in the new Azure portal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/active-directory-enterprise-apps-manage-provisioning#provisioning-modes)

As per this link,

> **Automatic** - This option appears if Azure AD supports automatic
>   API-based provisioning and/or de-provisioning of user accounts to this
>   application.

Is there a way I can enable automatic provisioning for Azure AD?

Answer (score 0):

The **Automated Provisioning** need the app supports. So it depends on which app you were config for.

All of the "Featured" apps in the Azure AD application gallery support automated user provisioning. [The list of featured apps can be viewed here](https://azuremarketplace.microsoft.com/en-us/marketplace/apps/category/azure-active-directory-apps?page=1&subcategories=featured)(refer [List of Apps that Support Automated User Provisioning](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/active-directory-saas-app-provisioning)).