# Azure Active Directory Enterprise App OpenID and User Provisioning (SCIM)

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I'm trying to build an Enterprise App in Azure that will support SSO using OpenID Connect and User Provisioning using a SCIM API.

When I create the application using the OpenID Connect approach I don't have an option to enable user provisioning. If I do the Non-gallery approach I can enable user provisioning and test out my SCIM API. Am I missing something? Why is that option not available for OpenID Connect?

I followed this diagram to pick the correct SSO. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/manage-apps/plan-sso-deployment#single-sign-on-options

[image]

Then selected the "App you're developing" option in Azure.

[image]

Once I go to the Provisioning part the "Get started" button is disable:

[image]

BUT if I choose the Non-Gallery option when creating the application the Provisioning part is enabled and allows we to step through the wizard to wireup to a SCIM API:
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [Azure ad app-provisioning-known-issues -microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/app-provisioning/known-issues#:%7E:text=Automatic%20provisioning%20isn%27t%20available%20on%20my%20OIDC%2Dbased%20application)

> If you create an app registration, the corresponding service principal
> in enterprise apps won't be enabled for automatic user provisioning.
> Your **app needs to be in the gallery to have provisioning enabled**.For
> that You'll need to either **request the app be added** to the gallery, if
> intended for use by multiple organizations, or create a second
> non-gallery app for provisioning.

To get your app in the gallery, see  [how to-**app gallery listing**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-howto-app-gallery-listing)

See [**SaaS App Integration Tutorials for use with Azure AD** | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/saas-apps/tutorial-list)

**References:**

1. [Azure AD Enterprise application not showing 'automatic' provisioning
   mode - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43669602/azure-ad-enterprise-application-not-showing-automatic-provisioning-mode)
2. [Problem configuring user provisioning to an Azure Active Directory
   Gallery app | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/app-provisioning/application-provisioning-config-problem)

Answer (score 1):

You've already identified what works right now - non-gallery OIDC apps can't support SCIM provisioning today, so you'll need a second app. We're (Microsoft) looking to enable the ability to enable SCIM provisioning on non-gallery OIDC apps, but there are some security/privilege escalation issues that need to be addressed first.

Comment: In @kavyasaraboju-MT ‘s answer it looks like it’s supported once the app has been approved. But are you saying you work for Microsoft and that’s not exactly true?

Comment: Both of us work for Microsoft in some capacity and I think both of our answers are correct. The big question is - is the app you're developing a SaaS app that would make sense to exist in the Azure AD Enterprise App gallery and be added by customers, or is it an app internal to your own company?

For the purpose of testing, you'll definitely need to do what I've suggested. If it's an app intended for your company's customers to use, you'll need to submit a request to have it onboarded to the AAD App Gallery, which for new provisioning requests can take several months.

Comment: Thanks. We are developing a SaaS app to be added by customers. In this case we are trying to build something like the SalesForce or Dropbox app that can be downloaded from the Gallery. So it sounds like we can make the OpenID app and then submit that to the gallery and while we wait create a second non-gallery app to test our SCIM API. Then once the first app, OpenID, is approved to the gallery the customers can download it and enable user provisioning.

Comment: Almost - you'll need to submit two requests, one for adding the OIDC SSO app, and a second to add SCIM provisioning to the OIDC app. There's a pretty lengthy backlog right now for the SCIM part, however, so as a short/medium term gap filler, your customers can use the non-gallery SCIM approach to connect to your SCIM APIs until you have a SCIM integration attached to the OIDC gallery app.

Comment: Would you be able to give a time on "lengthy"? I was hoping to have it up and running by the end of the year but wasn't going to start on it until August.

Comment: Right now it's measured in months - but we're working on some big changes that should improve this time by a significant amount and bring it down to a few weeks at worst. I can't really give anything more than that as there are a number of different factors that influence the development time.